# Filtering and replacing from multiple columns

Tags: python, r, linux, awk, sed

I have a file where i have to replace  pvalue greater than 0.05 (`pval > 0.05`) with `NA` , in other words retain the `pval < 0.05` and replace p`val > 0.05` with `NA` .

For example :

```
Rv_FC    Rv_Pval  Gc_FC  Gc_Pval ......
2          0.001   3      0.99
3          0.99    1      0.0002
3          0.0001  2      0.89
```

Output :

```
Rv_FC    Rv_Pval  Gc_FC  Gc_Pval ......
2          0.001   3      NA 
3          NA      1      0.0002
3          0.0001  2      NA
```

Only pval column should be considered and if the value of them is > 0.05 , it should be replaced with `NA`.

Advantage : pval columns are in 3rd, 5th , 7th ... columns..

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Provide your own attempt.

Comment: Just subset the columns that are `Pval` and replace i.e. `i1 <- [grep("Pval", names(df1); df1[i1][df1[i1] > 0.05\ <- NA`

Comment: Are you sure about the tags? Do you really want a solution involving [tag:python], [tag:r], [tag:linux], [tag:awk] and [tag:sed]?

Comment: Of course i tried in R, awk  and i came here when i couldn't do it..

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then share a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.  Then click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS = "\t" }NR==1{ for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ( $i ~"Pval" ) a[i]; print $0}NR>1{for ( i in a ) if ( $i > 0.5 ) $i = "NA"; print $0 }' file
```

Output:

```
Rv_FC    Rv_Pval  Gc_FC  Gc_Pval  
2        0.001     3      NA
3        NA        1      0.0002
3        0.0001    2      NA
```

Comment: Mhhhh..... that is strange. For me it works perfect. Did it produce any output at all?

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: for (i in 2:89 ) {
for(j in seq(3,47,2)){
if(tab[i,j] < 0.05){
print(tab[i,j])
}
}
}                                                                                                                          That's the R code i wrote , but it gave me the result in one straight line , basically i have 89 rows and 47 columns and the value starts from 3rd coloumn and is present in every alternate coloumns ,i.e. 5th , 7th ...

Comment: @ JFS31 : It worked!! a slight modification is $i > 0.05 and not $i > 0.5 , my bad i didn't check that .. Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: @vivekkashyap Glad I could help you. Then it would be nice if you could accept my answer.

Comment: @ JFS31 : I tried to upvote your answer but a small pop up appears on screen which says "Votes cast by less than 15 reputation are recorded but not publicly displayed". I am new to Stack overflow and my reputation points are less than 15 .. I am glad to accept ur answer ..

Comment: @vivekkashyap Acception is perfect. Thanks for that :)